# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Cont2#new No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"cont2"}, missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm very much new to Ruby on Rails. I have seen some similar questions posted on stack overflow but none of them helped/I didn't understand them..

**cont2_controller.rb** file:

```
class Cont2Controller < ApplicationController

  def act2

  end

  def new

  end

  def show
    @cont2=Cont2.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @cont2=Cont2.new(article_params)
    @cont2.save
    redirect_to @cont2
  end

  private def article_params
    params.require(:cont2).permit(:title,:text)
  end

end
```

views/cont2/ **new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with scope: :cont2,url: cont2_path,local: true do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :text %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

views/cont2/**show.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @cont2.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @cont2.text %>
</p>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources  :cont2
  root 'cont2#act2'
end
```

models/ **cont2.rb**

```
class Cont2 < ApplicationRecord
end
```

rake routes
[image: rake routes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in the console you do `rake routes` you'll see all the valid routes for your application. check out what route is used for a `post` (create) action.

If you're posting a form for a new `cont2` then the correct pat is not `cont2_path` ... that path is used to show or update an existing `cont2`and always requires a `cont2` object..  `cont2_path(@cont2)` or `cont2_path(@cont2.id)` which is why it's complaining about a missing id.

Your new form should be using the pluralized `cont2s_path` which doesn't reference an existing `cont2`

```
<%= form_with scope: :cont2, url: cont2s_path, local: true do |form| %>
```

Comment: undefined local variable or method `cont2s_path' for #<#<Class:0x00005612de41d2e0>:0x00005612de3c3470>
Did you mean?  cont2_path

Comment: And my controller name is cont2 , should controller name be defined as pluralized while declaring??   I have updated rake routes image as well pls see..

Comment: Yes, if you're using "resources"  as opposed to "resource" I would expect to see `resources :cont2s` in routes and the controller file name `cont2s_controller.rb` and the controller class `Cont2sController`

Comment: Defining controller name with plural solved the problem.. Thankyou..